# hyperopt result exceeds my hp.choice restriction, why? (XGBoost)

Tags: xgboost, hyperopt

I met a strange problem:
I defined my XGB hyper-parameter `'max_depth'` by hyperopt

```
hp.choice('max_depth',range(2,20))
```

But I got `'max_depth' = 0` or `1` result, which is not within `[2,20)` restriction. Why?
Anything I missed? 
Thanks.

Error result:

```
{'colsample_bytree': 0.18, 'learning_rate': 0.05, 'max_depth': 1, 'reg_alpha': 3.44, 'reg_lambda': 0.92}

{'colsample_bytree': 0.41, 'learning_rate': 0.09, 'max_depth': 0, 'reg_alpha': 0.14, 'reg_lambda': 3.53}

{'colsample_bytree': 0.71, 'learning_rate': 0.17, 'max_depth': 0, 'reg_alpha': 2.21, 'reg_lambda': 2.82}
```

```py
def xgb_classifier_tune(params):
    obj='binary:logistic' if class_nums==2 else 'multi:softmax'
    random.seed(time.time())
    xgb_model=xgb.XGBClassifier(
            max_depth=params['max_depth'],
            colsample_bytree=params['colsample_bytree'],
            learning_rate=params['learning_rate'],
            reg_alpha=params['reg_alpha'],
            reg_lambda=params['reg_lambda'],
            objective=obj,
            n_estimators=100000,
            random_state=random.randint(0,99999),
            n_jobs=-1)

    if params['max_depth']<2:
        return {'loss':999.999,'status': STATUS_FAIL,'info':[0,0,0,{}]}
    xgb_model.fit(tune_train_x,tune_train_y,eval_set=[(tune_valid_x,tune_valid_y)],verbose=1,early_stopping_rounds=100) #verbose: 0 (silent), 1 (warning), 2 (info), 3 (debug)
    predict_y=xgb_model.predict(tune_valid_x)
    f1,mcc,roc_auc,table=get_score(tune_valid_y[y_feature].values,predict_y)
    return 'loss':-mcc,'status': STATUS_OK

def xgb_hyper_tune():
    mdep=list(range(2,20))
    space={'max_depth':hp.choice('max_depth',mdep),
        'colsample_bytree':hp.uniform('colsample_bytree',0.1,0.9),
        'learning_rate':hp.quniform('learning_rate',0.01,0.2,0.01),
        'reg_alpha':hp.uniform('reg_alpha',0.1,6.0),
        'reg_lambda':hp.uniform('reg_lambda',0.1,6.0)}

    trials=Trials()
    best_param=fmin(xgb_classifier_tune,space,algo=tpe.suggest,max_evals=100, trials=trials)
    return best_param
```

Answer (score 6):

I also faced the same problem. It is not an error.

From the [official document](https://github.com/hyperopt/hyperopt/wiki/FMin#21-parameter-expressions) of `hyperopt`, it is not understandable. But [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54978278/hyperopt-result-exceeds-my-hp-choice-restriction-why-xgboost#57789975) of zilin xiang and [this](https://github.com/hyperopt/hyperopt/issues/550#issuecomment-545971248) very nice explanation of  ncalik helped me to understand the reason of occurring the problem. [This](https://github.com/hyperopt/hyperopt/issues/584#issuecomment-562698245) helped me to solve the problem.

**Reason for Occurring the Problem**

It is due to using `hp.choice()` and due to not setting `return_argmin=False` inside the `fmin()`. Since you have set `max_depth` [2,20), getting index 0 or 1 means that it is using `max_depth` 2 (for index 0) or 3 (for index 1).

**Solving the Problem**

If you want to get the actual parameter, instead of index, then, you can use two approaches.

1. use `hyperopt.space_eval()`: `hyperopt.space_eval(space, best_param)`.
2. set `return_argmin=False` in `fmin()`: `best_param=fmin(xgb_classifier_tune,space,algo=tpe.suggest,max_evals=100, trials=trials, return_argmin=False)`. Instead of the index, it will return you the actual values of the parameters.

To know more, you may check [this](https://github.com/hyperopt/hyperopt/issues/584#issuecomment-562698245).

Answer (score 5):

Because `hp.choice` will return the index instead of value of item in your restriction. For example, `0` means the value of `max_depth` is 2.